# Cookies doesn't work in sub services pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, pickle

The task is simple.
Go to the service https://mail.ru/
Load cookies.
Go to the subservice with the same cookies https://x.calendar.mail.ru/

Manually - it works. As soon as they are loaded from a file, when switching to the second service, the cookies are deleted. I don't understand what the problem is?

Code:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import pickle

from utils.navigate import navigate, coockies_load

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)


def main():
    navigate(driver, "https://mail.ru/", 20)

    coockies_load(driver)

    navigate(driver, "https://x.calendar.mail.ru/", 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

File navigate.py

```py
import os
import time
import pickle
import time

def navigate(driver, url: str, sec: int):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(sec)

def coockies_load(driver):
    if os.path.exists('cookies.pkl'):
        for cookie in pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb")):
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        print('Загрузили файл куки')
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        navigate(driver, "https://mail.ru/", 5)
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
        print('Сохранили файл куки')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: why would you need to load the cookies?  They've already been set.  Are you confirming that the cookies for the subdomain are not set explicitly for that subdomain?

Comment: the next time you run the script they need to be loaded, as far as I know. But they are loaded only once. Not the second time. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I would check the cookies in the browser's dev tools.  There you can check for things like: 1) are these session cookies? (if so, they are only good for the session)  2) Are they set to the full domain?  Subdomains can sometimes read main domain cookies, but it depends on how they are set.  3) Are they set as http-only, same-site, etc... and how does that effect things here?  4) are CORS rules involved?

Comment: for "remember me" type cookies, usually the easiest thing do to is to manually create a new browser profile and manually login/navigate to the site so that the cookies/storage are set.  Then use that profile when launching the webdriver.